# How can I plot points that have four units associated with them on a 2D plot with four axes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, axis

I would like to do something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s98Q1.png).

All the other examples I looked at plotted two different curves for each pair of axes, but I would like a way to combine four variables into a single point and plot all points. This naturally implies that the axes are not going to have the same dimension and/or order of magnitude.

Comment: Is it really possible to represent 4 dimensional data on a 2D plot? Can you plot a sample by hand and post it here so that we can understand what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, the Hertzsprung–Russell diagram (HR diagram) would be an example. [Here is an image of it.](https://xrtpub.cfa.harvard.edu/graphics/edu/formal/variable_stars/HR_diagram.jpg)
What I want to do is something simpler, [like this plot I've done manualy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s98Q1.png)

Comment: From what I understand, HR diagrams have a connection between the 2 variables on the X axis and the 2 on the Y axis, so it's essentially 2D data. Is this the case for you as well?

Comment: Yes. I am using 3 of them (experimental data) to calculate a 4th. If I use theoretical calculations, I can use two variables to generate a third axis and join these three to calculate the last value of interest. But I would prefer not to do that.
If I can make a 2D graph and somehow adjust these two secondary X and Y axes in some way, I'm already happy. To clarify further, what I am looking for is a way of plotting secondary axes on a 2D chart where their scale is determined by a range of values that I already have independently of the data that is already on the chart.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at least with matplolib. You can only label x and y axes of a 2D plot.

Comment: I see. Well, thank you anyway.